# How do you search for symbols in ace editor autocomplete?

Tags: regex, ace-editor

I am using the Ace editor autocomplete plugin. I have some values in my completer that may have symbols. For example:

```
getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
    callback(null, _.map(fields, function (field) {
        return {
            name: "ParentName.ChildName",
            value: "ParentName.ChildName",
            meta: "field"
        };
    });
};
```

If I type in "ParentName." in the editor the popup/picker disappears. I have tried escaping the value like "ParentName\.". Any ideas on this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in ace autocompleter it only accepts completions that match word regex, instead of keeping popup open as long as there is matching completion. You can report an issue at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/new.